# How to get values from multiple fields in LWC

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I have around 100 fields on the components mostly checkboxes and input fields and I'm not sure what is the best way to get the values and I' have written the following code but I'm not sure if I'm practicing the best practices/pattern, can anyone shed some light on it?

HTML:

```
<lightning-input type="text" label="First Name" name="fname" onchange={handleFormInputChange}></lightning-input>
<lightning-input type="text" label="Last Name" name="lname" onchange={handleFormInputChange}></lightning-input>
<lightning-input type="number" label="Age" name="age" onchange={handleFormInputChange}></lightning-input>
.......
......
......up to 100 different fields
```

JS

```
handleFormInputChange( event ) {

        switch ( event.target.name ) { 
            case "fname":
                this.firstName = event.detail.value;
                break;
            case "lname":            
                this.lastName = event.detail.value;
                break;
            case "age":            
                this.age = event.detail.value;
                break;
            .....
            .....
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your JS you can have one object, which stores values for the field. At the same time name of the `lightning-input` should be a unique name of the field:

**HTML**

```
<lightning-input type="text" label="First Name" name="FirstName" onchange={handleFormInputChange}></lightning-input>
<lightning-input type="text" label="Last Name" name="LastName" onchange={handleFormInputChange}></lightning-input>
<lightning-input type="number" label="Age" name="Age" onchange={handleFormInputChange}></lightning-input>
.......
......
......up to 100 different fields
```

**JS**

```
container = {};

handleFormInputChange(event) {
    this.container[event.target.name] = event.detail.value;
}
```

---

or as mentioned by Brian in the comments, it is possible to store field values separately

**JS**

```
handleFormInputChange(event) {
    this[event.target.name] = event.detail.value;
}
```

The key moment here, that `name` of the `lightning-input` is the name of the field to which value will be assigned.

Comment: You can also use `this` directly: `this[event.target.name] = event.target.value`.

Comment: @sfdcfox yes, editing my question now :)

Comment: for checkbox then `event.detail.checked`